# where do you place jquery for smooth scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".navbar a").on('click', function(event) {

        var hash = this.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 900, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    });
})

</script>
```

to make my href links in the nav bar of deliciousproductions.com.au smooth scroll to the position on the page but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm following instructions off of w3 school and this is literally all they use. I haven't included a footer thing which they add with a comma after

```
$(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event)
```

Is it something to do with the scrollTop: line? the 900 is the milliseconds defined for it to take to travel. The buttons use href="#about" and the section id="about" so I can't figure out why it's not working. I'm reffering to jquery in the document under

```
</body>
```

and I'm using the script above in a

```
<script>
```

tag inside the

```
<body>
```

but at the very bottom under all content

Also hitting enter and pressing space four times just to write

```
<body> is getting really annoying how do you do it easier on stackoverflow?
```

Comment: Please show an example the html for your links and the sections they scroll to

Comment: sorry I didn't include them to begin with I thought it was irrelevant because I know the hrefs are correct and it's a pretty easy bit of code to href to an id. cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script tags of jQuery and bootstrap are neither in body nore in head.

check your console output:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

To fix this, add the below to your `<head>` tag:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>‌`

Comment: @lopu what Chris means is, you need to import jQuery into your page by adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>` tag.  Chris, when you answer a question please include an answer not just a statement telling the OP what is wrong, that is not very helpful to someone new to the language :)

Comment: oh guys I had these in my html doc, <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js">
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"> and I hadn't closed them. I put them inside my head instead of under body and it works now :) cheers

Comment: can you enable smooth scrolling without writing the scipt in the html doc? Do I just put it in a .js and src it?

edit: yep

Comment: @lopu Correct, you can put your javascript in a file named something like  `myScripts.js` and add a link to it in your head tag like `<script src="myScripts.js"></script>` just like you did with jquery. Just remember that if the code in myScripts.js uses jquery, it must be loaded underneath `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>` or you will get the same error you started with